# Convert from ITM ref to GPS ref?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, c#, coordinate-system, wgs84

How can I convert from ITM ref (Israel new map) to GPS ref and from GPS ref to ITM ref?

I need any C# sample code or formula for this.

For example: 32.086156,34.769239 = 178364,665948
Or : 29.548783,34.952316 = 194997,384546

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By 'GPS ref' I'll take it you mean WGS84 based geographic coordinates. ITM looks to be [EPSG:2039 on spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2039/), which includes the [ESRI WKT](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2039/esriwkt/). From your tags, it sounds like you're trying to do this transformation within ArcGIS, which can be accomplished using the ESRI WKT and something like the [C# Projection Engine wrapper](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15716).

There's a [C# wrapper for Proj.4](http://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/Public/BDB/Tools/proj4/) which could also be used. Here's the conversion done interactively with GDAL using Proj.4:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.73439361111111 \
+lon_0=35.20451694444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 \ 
+ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-48,55,52,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs' -s_srs epsg:4326
```